# raw_input("") has been eliminated from python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have tried a lot to run `raw_input("")` on the python console but that gives an error. Moreover I watch some videos that might have been made on old python. so `input("")` is the only method and why `raw_input("")` is discarded in the new version is there any reason ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`raw_input()` was renamed to `input()` in Python v3.x

The old `input()` is gone, but you can emulate it with `eval(input())`

[What's new in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html) will mention this (and more):

> [PEP 3111](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/): raw_input() was renamed to [input()](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input). That is, the new input()
>   function reads a line from sys.stdin and returns it with the trailing
>   newline stripped. It raises EOFError if the input is terminated
>   prematurely. To get the old behavior of input(), use eval(input()).

Answer (score 5):

Python 3.x's `input` *is* python 2.x's `raw_input`. The function has just been renamed since the old 2.x `input` was broken by design and therefore eliminated in 3.x.

Comment: I wouldn't have said it was "broken by design", but rather that it was "ill-advised". Removing it was a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that the old input() function tries to convert things you type as if it's python code. It generates lot of security issues, that's mainly why it was discarded for the raw_input instead but renamed input() because, well, you know, we programmers are a little bit lazy and typing input() instead of raw_input takes 4 less characters so...